# Обнаружение перехода на новую строку в html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5, css3

Здравствуйте! Интересует следующее, есть у меня к примеру пара блоков c тегами заголовков, которые содержат текст, имеющийся текст не будет влезать в одну строку, то есть он будет перебрасываться на новую строку из-за не влезания в ширину блока, мне нужно как-то найти эти не явные переходы на новую строку в блоке и к примеру заменить на что-то, если это вообще возможно [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Свойство *text-overflow* у *css* не подходит?

Comment: Подходит), не знал о таком свойстве.. спасибо, а то писал бы велосипед.. по гуглению видимо не правильно вопрос ставил

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно вы про это:

```
.БЕЗ_ПЕРЕНОСОВ
{
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если в заголовке лежит просто текст без фокусов, то надо обеспечить его нахождение в одной текстовой ноде. Для части текста этой ноды можно будет определять область, которую он занимает. Соответственно, изменение высоты этой области в большинстве случаев означает перенос строки. Известное исключение - высота начальных пробелов составляет 0.

```
function getRangeHeight(textNode, len) {
    var range = document.createRange();
    range.setStart(textNode, 0);
    range.setEnd(textNode, len);
    var rect = range.getBoundingClientRect();
    return rect.height || rect.bottom - rect.top;
}
```

Обращаю внимание, что `textNode` - это именно текстовый узел, являющийся единственным потомком dom-элемента. И осторожно, при пустом элементе он может не существовать.

А jQuery тут ничем не поможет. Если только кто-то уже написал плагин. Но так как пояснений, что именно надо сделать, в вопросе нет, то и плагин посоветовать нельзя.